# Qt Widget is partly clipped due to change in PC display settings

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qt5, dpi

I have QDialog in the Qt Application which is of fixed size. When the "scale and layout" in the display settings of the pc is changed from 100% to 150%, the widget is partly clipped.

Here is the code:

```
void windowsDpiScale()
{

    const HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
    const int dpiX = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSX);
    const int dpiY = GetDeviceCaps(hDC, LOGPIXELSY);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);

    // Perform the scaling.
    MulDiv(100, dpiX, 96);
    MulDiv(100, dpiY, 96);
}
int main()
{
    windowsDpiScale();
    QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps); //HiDPI pixmaps
    QApplication main_application(argc, argv);
}
```

I have also tried setting qputenv("QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR","1"); and QGuiApplication::setDesktopSettingsAware(false); but it did not help. I am using Qt version 5.8. Any suggestions on how I can fix the UI so that the scale,text and other items of the system settings doesn't change?

Answer (score 0):

Using layouts and not using fixed sizes or positions for child widgets or the top-level widget will solve these problems if you implement them correctly. Most problems of the type you are seeing is because you haven't used Qt's layout system.

Look to [this](https://forum.qt.io/topic/87971/my-ui-is-desktop-dependent-i-want-it-to-be-desktop-resolution-independent)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't help. I want my application to be independent of the PC Display Settings.